# Find the highest sum among the decreasing sequence of elements in an array

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

For example we have an array like

{9,8,7,9,5,4,10,3,12}

Now the decreasing sequences are

9,8,7 => 9+8+7 = 24

9,5,4 => 9+5+4 = 18

10,3 => 10+3 =13

12 => 12

In the above summation 24 is the highest and we have to print that value as the result.

Built in functions like array list should not be used

Need a dynamic answer and the answer must satisfy all the other arrays of this type

The code I used is

```
int[] arr2 = new int[8] { 10, 9, 8, 9, 7, 6, 11, 5 };
            int temp2 = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= arr2.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i - 1; j <= arr2.Length - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (arr2[j] > arr2[i])
                    {
                        temp2 = temp2 + arr2[i]+arr2[j];
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: This feels like a homework question...

Comment: any idea on how to solve this....

Comment: You should only need to loop over the list once keeping track of the running sum and when you see the end of a decreasing sequence (by keeping track of the previous value) compare the running sum to a max sum, reset the sum and continue.  Don't forget to check the running sum after the loop as well.

Comment: `int max = int.MinValue;

      for (int i = 1, prior = array[0], sum = prior; i < array.Length; prior = array[i++]) 
        max = Math.Max(sum = array[i] + (array[i] < prior ? sum : 0), max); Console.Wrie(max);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic, unoptimized:

```
int[] arr = { 9, 8, 7, 9, 5, 4, 10, 3, 12 };
int maxSum = 0;
int curSum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    // new sequence
    if(curSum == 0)
    {
        curSum = arr[i];
    }
    // seqence decreasing
    else if(arr[i] <= arr[i - 1])
    {
        curSum += arr[i];
    }
    // end of sequence
    else
    {
        // check if the sequence produced a greater sum
        if(maxSum < curSum)
        {
            maxSum = curSum;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(curSum);
        curSum = arr[i];
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(curSum);
// final check
if(curSum > maxSum)
{
    maxSum = curSum;
}

Console.WriteLine($"Max: {maxSum}");
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but I think it will give you a general idea of how to proceed.

```
public int FindMaxDecreasing(int[] arr)
{
    //Store the max value
    var max = 0;
    //The current running total
    var temp = 0;
    //Store the previous value
    var previous = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
         //Check if first element or decreasing value
         if(i == 0 += arr[i] < previous)
         {
            //Add to temp if it is
            temp += arr[i];
         }

         else
         { 
             //Swap out max value if temp is larger
             if(temp > max)
             {
                 max = temp;
             }

             //Restart temp
              temp = arr[i];
          }

         //Assign previous
         previous = arr[i];
    }

    if(temp > max)
    {
        max = temp;
    }

    return max;
}
```